# Matplotlib, TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm not a professional user of python, and I'm writing a (supposed) simple code with matplotlib to produce a histogram from a column of numbers and fit it with a Gaussian.

I try to save the output with matplotlib.pyplot.savefig("figure.ps"), but I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "histo.py", line 85, in <module>
    plt.savefig("histo.ps")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 471, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1185, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2021, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 421, in draw
     self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 898, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1997, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1042, in draw
    ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 993, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 747, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 309, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 188, in get_text_width_height_descent
    renderer=self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 608, in get_text_width_height_descent
    page = iter(dvi).next()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 65, in __iter__
    have_page = self._read()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 120, in _read
    byte = ord(self.file.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

the strangest thing is that with other columns or numbers it doesn't give me errors at all, but the column of numbers that gives me the error doesn't contain peculiar characters. I guess that the main error message is:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

but I cannot understand why. The column contains 3000 numbers now, and typically I have run this code also with 10000 without problems. However, in this case, I noticed that if I reduce the column from 3000 to 2000 numbers, the code stops to complain
Moreover, keeping the 3000 numbers column, if I don't try to save the output plot, the code doesn't crash either.

Is there anyone who can give me some suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the file reached the end (returing an empty string signals EOF).

Comment: The error message seems to be related to LaTeX.  Are you using any LaTeX text for labels etc.?

Comment: In the file are contained two columns of numbers. I obtain this error only running this code on one of them. if it was a EOF signal, wouldn't it appear also for the other column? However, I've checked and no empty lines are present at the end of the file...

Comment: Oh,yes! at the beginning I import:

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

and if I comment it I have no problem!! but it never gave to me errors until now, how it is possible?
however, thank you!!!! I was going mad!! how did you understand it was a LaTeX error?

Comment: That is a problem... if I delete the imports, the plot I save with savefig is impossible to be shown. I get this error when I try to open it with evince, for example:
> ev_document_misc_pixbuf_from_surface: assertion `surface' failed
> GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Comment: Can it be a problem of the matplotlib version I'm using? the version is 1.1.1rc, and the backend is TkAgg

Answer (score 1):

The error is arising from latex compiling something of length 0. The question is, why is this happening.

Each time matplotlib generates a plot that requires tex, if the latex items in the figure have not been compiled before, they are compiled and then stored in ~/.matplotlib/tex.cache/. This way, if you have axis labels, for instance, that are reused among many plots, matplotlib doesn't need to worry about recompiling the latex for them. This is true even if you are saving to a different mounted space than where your home directory resides. Thus, if you run out of room in your home directory, when you try to save a plot the tex cache cannot be added to, resulting in the above error.

All in all, a tricky find, but sometimes it pays to read the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html):

### Troubleshooting¶

Try deleting your .matplotlib/tex.cache directory. If you don’t know
where to find .matplotlib, see *.matplotlib directory location*.